# Rails Heroku application error

Tags: heroku

I try to push my rails application to heroku but encountered the following error

```
Application Error

An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

Because I am using sqlite3
A search on the web show I should do the following

```
heroku rake db:create
heroku rake db:migrate
```

the heroku rake db:create failed by complaining

```
Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter` (pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)
```

The command `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter` failed and complains

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'activerecord-postgresql-adapter' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: activerecord-postgis-adapter, activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter, activerecord-postgresql-cursors, activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter, activerecord-jdbcmssql-adapter
```

Then I searched the web again and followed the http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/how-do-i-use-sqlite3-for-development suggestion to change

```
gem 'sqlite3'
```

to

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

and run

```
bundle install --without production
```

however this did not solve the problem
another source say I need to do like

```
group :production do
   gem 'therubyracer-heroku', '0.8.1.pre3'
   gem "pg"
end
```

This also failed to solve the issue

I have postresql installed on my system.
So what hell is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The key thing here is that the `pg` gem is required to run against the Postgres database that you end up using when you deploy to heroku (http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/database)

Ideally, you want to be running Postgres locally so that you're not seeing any differences between development and production from a database standpoint.

If you want to stick with things how you have them simply adding `gem "pg"` to your Gemfile should fix this.

Once added, run:

```
bundle install
git add .
git commit -am "Added PG to Gemfile"
git push heroku master
heroku rake db:migrate
```

Comment: I exactly followed your instruction. The webpage now change from Application Error to We're sorry, but something went wrong.

We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly.       ------what this means? It is my problem or heroku's problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please following steps for deploy on heroku server

First please remove the gem ='sqlite3' from Gemfile and add gem = 'pg'

Run this command on Project path: **bundle install**

**git add .**

**git commit -am "add pg on gem file"**

**git push heroku master**